# Has anyone use sonar scala plugin successfully?

Tags: scala, maven, sonarqube

Has anyone successfully used sonar-scala plugin when using "maven sonar:sonar"?  I got NullPointerException caused by

> at java.io.File.(File.java:277)     at
>   org.sonar.batch.scan.filesystem.DeprecatedFileSystemAdapter.resolvePath(DeprecatedFileSystemAdapter.java:132)
>     at
>   org.sonar.plugins.scala.surefire.SurefireSensor.analyse(SurefireSensor.java:53)
>     at
>   org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:72)

Answer (score 0):

As of today (March 12th, 2014), the Scala plugin has not been released yet as you can see it on [its documentation page](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Scala+Plugin).

Note that this effort is only driven by the community, so you have to periodically check this page (or subscribe to announcements on the user mailing list) to know if/when you can use this plugin.